# Using Japanese and Thai in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, language-support, input, japanese

I have just installed ubuntu 16.04 and installed Japanese and Thai, I've followed the steps which I found in other posts for how to get Japanese working.
However, when Thai is also installed a strange thing happens.
If I switch to Japanese and start typing, it works ok.  But if I switch to Thai, then when I go back to Japanese it doesn't work - the language bar icon says Japanese but it still types in Thai.

I've tried changing the input modes but that doesn't help.  I can get the Japanese working again by going to Text Entry setttings then clicking on Japanese (Mozc) (IBus), then clicking on the little tool icon and then 'restore defaults', but if I cycle through the languages again it causes the same problem again.

Does anybody know if there's a way that I can switch back and forth between English, Thai and Japanese without this problem?  I know that this is probably not a problem that many people are going to encounter as it's an odd mix of languages.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the problem and it seems to work ok now.  Rather than delete my question I'll leave it here (as it is quite specific so it may help someone in future)

Basically if you still have the keyboard input method system as IBus then there is some kind of conflict between the Thai and the Japanese.  One or the other worked fine for me, but having both installed caused a problem.
Go to Language support, switch input method to fcitx, restart your computer (or log out and in again) and instead of the little EN, TH, JA up in the top right corner there will be a little keyboard icon.  The bad news is that you can't tell at a glance what language you're currently in, but the good news is that all three languages work properly.

the answer was from this post originally,
[16.04 Japanese Text Input not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772642/16-04-japanese-text-input-not-working)