# Japanese input works only in search menu

Tags: keyboard, japanese, mozc

I followed this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/a/772715/652678) to install Japanese input. Unfortunately, the only place where it works for me is the search menu that is opened by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> key. Everywhere else it's just regular English keyboard. I tried rebooting, uninstalling Japanese language and Mozc and then re-doing the installation process. I also tried enabling Japanese(Anthy) input source but result was the same. I also tried following the tutorial on a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 VM and it worked perfectly there. It seems that this problem is not reproducible so I'm hoping someone encountered literally the same problem and can help me.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS

Input method: Japanese (Mozc)

Keyboard input method system: IBus, also tried Fcitx4

Answer (score 0):

Using Terminal

Method #1

```
rm $HOME/.mozc/.server.lock
rm $HOME/.mozc/.session.ipc

reboot
```

Method #2

```
reset-mozc

 reboot
```

---

Using GUI

1. Open Settings > Region & Language
2. Click on the Installed Language Tab
3. Remove Japanese
4. Reboot

I have no problem to type Japanese without Japanese language installed. If you like to have Japanese language on the system, you can go ahead install it again. All I need are the Japanese fonts.

---

Simple installation of fcitx-mozc input method.

```
sudo apt install fcitx-mozc
im-config -n fcitx

reboot

fcitx-autostart
```