# Japanese input only works for system tools

Tags: keyboard-layout, ibus, japanese, fcitx

I'm running Ubuntu 23.04 "Lunar" (on Xorg, if that matters). Altough configured correctly(?) most of my windows don't respect my current input method:

I've configured Japanese Input with fcitx5-mozc, as secondary input method next to English. I can switch between the two and Japanese input works as expected (inputting Kana, with conversion options to Kanji), but only in a few select windows:

- The ubuntu notepad-thingy (successor of gedit)
- The ubuntu settings dialog
- The ubuntu application search (when pressing the super key once)
- Nautilus

On other windows, sadly all the interesting ones, it keeps inputting only Latin characters:

- Firefox
- Thunderbird
- Libreoffice
- Chromium
- gnome-terminal/bash

**What I have tried**: I completely switched the setup from fcitx5 to IBUS and Anthy. Interestingly enough, I have exactly the same result: the same windows work and don't work as listed above.

I also think [Question 1458571](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458571/japanese-input-works-only-in-search-menu) might be a duplicate of this, but the provided solution does not apply, it's only for fcitx.

How can I get this to work in all applications/windows?

**Edit**
As per request, my relevant environment variables:

```
$ env | grep -E 'XMOD|_IM'
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

Also, I've set it to "Use the same source for all windows". Setting it to "Switch input sources individually for each window". Has no discernable effect, neither worse nor better.

**Edit 2**
I've done the following:

- Select fcitx5 over IBUS
- Reboot
- Verified fcitx5-mozc is installed
- Checked my env-variables again:

```
  GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
  XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
  CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
  SDL_IM_MODULE=fcitx
  QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
```

- Realized, I cannot select Japanese (mozc) as input option in the settings:[image: Ubuntu keyboard settings]
- Added mozc as input method to fcitx: [image: fcitx settings]

I now have somehow only one active input method, can switch between mozc and ... non-mozc(?) Using the top toolbar. When mozc is active, it now works for all windows, so basically my initial question is answered.

Since I only have one active input method I can no longer switch between the two using Super+Space... and I think my setup is still somehow weird/broken. But for the few occasions I need to input Japanese I think i can live with it.

Comment: I do not know Japanese, but I use other foreign languages, and I am aware that there is a setting that allows you to change the input language either only in one window or in all windows. I just want to be sure that you are aware of that.

Comment: @ThomasHedden yes, good point. I *am* aware of the setting. And confirm the current setting by viewing the icon in the top bar

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson i've added the env variables to my question

Comment: Those variable values should be fine as long as you use IBus. But to use fxitx5, you need to first open the Language Support tool, change the "Keyboard input method system" to Fcitx5, and reboot.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson using your tips, I managed to arrive at a somewhat workable solution.

Comment: Good. No, your solution is not broken. You need to remember that IBus is the IM framework which is integrated into GNOME, while fcitx5 is not, so when you use fcitx5 the built-in input source tools are disabled. It's unclear to me, though, why you didn't make IBus work in all windows. It should have worked with Anthy, and actually the package `ibus-mozc` exists too.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson That is a good point. I have to say that from my (developer, but not on OS level) laymans standpoint, it is difficult to understand the difference between an IM Framwork, an IM ... client? Implementation? And then there's keyboard layout and language settings... oh well. I might experimentally switch back to IBus when I have the time. In any case, you helped me a lot. Thank you very much for your time.